# Can we create plasma with other things except gas?

Tags: water, electric-fields, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

In my school book its written on how plasma is created and it is said that we can create plasma by ionizing a gas but i have heard that plasma can be created even from liquids like water and also from grapes (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwTjsRt0Fzo). So does it mean that we can create plasma with many things other that gases?

Comment: Isnt the video fake? Did someone try?

Comment: @jaromrax I would imagine that the video has some validity as the channel that is conducting the experiment (and yes usually youtube is not a goto source) is quite serious and tends to entertain well researched topics and information.

Comment: I wonder, that I dont see this effect frequently in a microwave myself.

Comment: To create a plasma requires that one ionize enough of the material that the number density of ionized particles is large and the corresponding plasma frequency greatly exceeds neutral collision rates.  The later condition is important to make sure that the neutral particles do not control the dynamics of the system (though technically, it could still be a plasma).  In any case, kicking an electron off of an atom generally takes more energy than breaking chemical bonds.  So in most cases, the substance will be reduced to its constituent parts before becoming a plasma.

Comment: Video is not fake. It is incredibly easy to run this demonstration yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plasma can be created from many substances. More importantly, plasma can have the same density as liquids or solids, or even much more dense.

One case widely-studied nowadays is the laser-produced plasma. By focusing an intense laser on matter, the electric field of the laser light can be so strong to ionize atoms very quickly (less than a femtosecond) thus produce ionized matter, which is a plasma. People use many types of solids, such as plastics, aluminium, iron, gold, tungsten, etc. In fact, it is possible to create plasmas much denser that the solids from which they originate by compressing them using lasers. More precisely, it is possible to launch shock waves through the ionized solids, thus reaching high densities, high pressures and high temperatures. These conditions are close to those of the interior of stars of planets. As a consequence, these plasmas can provide information on geological or astrophysical phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

A plasma is, by its nature a gas - it has no structure and the constituent particles are not strongly bound to each other. Well, at least it's approximately a gas, and it's certainly not a liquid or a solid, but has been described as "the fourth state of matter" http://pluto.space.swri.edu/image/glossary/plasma.html

But it's easy (or  at least straightforward) to *create* a plasma from either a solid or a liquid - you just apply either high enough heat or electric current to the material. A welder's arc, for instance, is a plasma, and is created from solid metal.

Answer (score 0):

In a plasma the particles are very hot. So hot that the atoms move so fast and collide so hard that they kick off electrons from each other and create ions. Molecules are hardly stable at these conditions. At these temperatures everything is no longer solid or liquid. So you can make plasma with everything like water, iron, tungsten, etc, but they will evaporate in the process.

Answer (score 0):

YES, plasma is create plasma by microwave oven,grapes watch glass plate and a beaker.
procedure-
1- Cut the grape by the help of knife but not completly, leave very little and 
   thin joint between the pices.
2- Put it into a watch glass plate and cover it through the beaker.
3- Put tihs into the microwave oven and switch it ON.For fifteen minutes
   Temperature=150^0c.
   And after 15 minutes you can see the plasma.

Comment: can you provide a source for this procedure? have you done the experiment yourself?